# Uncaught ReferenceError: takepic is not defined (Intel XDK)

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

Vi na internet um exemplo para capturar foto no app. Estou debugando e aparece esse erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: takepic is not defined

Meu código:

```
function takepic(){
        intel.xdk.camera.takePicture(10,true, "jpg");
    }
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.camera.picture.add", function(event){
        var nomeFoto = event.filename;
        var url = intel.xdk.camera.getPictureURL(nomeFoto);
        document.getElementById("ocorrenciaFoto1").setAttribute("src", url);
    });
```

Botão que faz a ação:

```
<button onclick="takepic()" class="btn widget uib_w_50 d-margins btn-lg btn-primary" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera button-icon-top" data-position="top"></i>Foto</button>
```

O que esta errado?

Comment: Tente colocar ao invés do `onclick` no html, um `.addEventListener("click", takepic)` no botão, no javascript. É importante a função venha sem parênteses.

Comment: @SamirBraga você poderia postar o código como deve ficar abaixo?

Comment: Claro, não é certeza de funionar, mas não custa tentar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
function takepic() {
  intel.xdk.camera.takePicture(10, true, "jpg");
}
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.camera.picture.add", function(event) {
  var nomeFoto = event.filename;
  var url = intel.xdk.camera.getPictureURL(nomeFoto);
  document.getElementById("ocorrenciaFoto1").setAttribute("src", url);
});
var button = document.getElementById("takeAPicture");
button.addEventListener("click", takepic);
```

Adicione um `id="takeAPicture"` no seu button e remova o `onclick="takepic()"`.